# CSS spinner sequence not working smoothly in iOS Chrome?

Tags: html, ios, css, google-chrome, css-animations

I have a CSS spinner that works everywhere except on iOS Chrome. In iOS Chrome the animation is very jerky and is breaking the intended smooth sequence. Here is the code I have at the moment:

**HTML**

```
<div class="spinner">
    <span class="child1"></span>
    <span class="child2"></span>
    <span class="child3"></span>
    <span class="child4"></span>
    <span class="child5"></span>
    <span class="child6"></span>
    <span class="child7"></span>
    <span class="child8"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@keyframes loader {
  0% {
      background-color: #ffffff;
  }
  100% {
      background-color: transparent;
  }
}
.spinner {
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    transform: scale(0.6);
    width: 100px;
}
.spinner span {
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-duration: 1.04s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: loader;
    background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
}
.spinner span.child1 {
    animation-delay: 0.39s;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -8px;
    top: 0;
}
.spinner span.child2 {
    animation-delay: 0.52s;
    left: 71px;
    top: 13px;
}
.spinner span.child3 {
    animation-delay: 0.65s;
    margin-top: -8px;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
}
.spinner span.child4 {
    animation-delay: 0.78s;
    left: 71px;
    top: 72px;
}
.spinner span.child5 {
    animation-delay: 0.91s;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -8px;
}
.spinner span.child6 {
    animation-delay: 1.04s;
    left: 13px;
    top: 72px;
}
.spinner span.child7 {
    animation-delay: 1.17s;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -8px;
    top: 50%;
}
.spinner span.child8 {
    animation-delay: 1.3s;
    left: 13px;
    top: 13px;
}
```

I have all the CSS prefixes as well `-webkit-`, `-o-`, `-ms-`...
If anyone can shed some light on where it is I'm going wrong, that'd be great.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdmYaQ

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I had 2 animations on the page going off at the same time which was causing a lag. Also see: http://chrissilich.com/blog/fix-css-animation-slow-or-choppy-in-mobile-browsers/